# Java type generated by multiple managed types errors after "migrating" to AndroidX

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, androidx

### Original Question:

I am currently running into this error after I, as dumb as this sounds, clicked one to many times on "migrate to AndroidX":

```
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnQueryTextListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnCloseListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog+IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_RecyclerListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+IRecyclerListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar_SnackbarActionClickImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.Design.Widget.Snackbar+SnackbarActionClickImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar+IOnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuItemHoverListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.IMenuItemHoverListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu+IOnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout_OnAttachListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.ContentFrameLayout+IOnAttachListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnMultiChoiceClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog+IDialogInterfaceOnMultiChoiceClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog+IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_RecyclerListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.    Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.    Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout_OnOffsetChangedListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_OnChildAttachStateChangeListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+IOnChildAttachStateChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_TabListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.App.ActionBar+ITabListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_OnMenuVisibilityListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.App.ActionBar+IOnMenuVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewStubCompat_OnInflateListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.ViewStubCompat+IOnInflateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnSuggestionListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_OnNavigationListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar+IOnNavigationListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.ActionMenuView+IOnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout_OnOffsetChangedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Google.Android.Material.AppBar.AppBarLayout+IOnOffsetChangedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_TabListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView+IOnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout_OnAttachListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout_OnAttachListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.ContentFrameLayout+IOnAttachListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.com.google.android.material.behavior.SwipeDismissBehavior_OnDismissListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar+IOnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+IOnItemTouchListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup_OnFitSystemWindowsListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.IFitWindowsViewGroupOnFitSystemWindowsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_ItemAnimator_ItemAnimatorFinishedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+ItemAnimator+IItemAnimatorFinishedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog+IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewStubCompat_OnInflateListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.ViewStubCompat+IOnInflateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnSuggestionListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView+IOnSuggestionListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnMultiChoiceClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog+IDialogInterfaceOnMultiChoiceClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_TabListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar+ITabListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Google.Android.Material.Navigation.NavigationView+IOnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuItemHoverListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.   Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewStubCompat_OnInflateListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.    Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup_OnFitSystemWindowsListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.IFitWindowsViewGroupOnFitSystemWindowsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.PopupMenu+IOnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_OnNavigationListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.App.ActionBar+IOnNavigationListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMenuView+IOnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu_OnDismissListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu+IOnDismissListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider_OnShareTargetSelectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.ShareActionProvider+IOnShareTargetSelectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuItemHoverListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.IMenuItemHoverListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_OnNavigationListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.behavior.SwipeDismissBehavior_OnDismissListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.Design.Widget.SwipeDismissBehavior+IOnDismissListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnMultiChoiceClickListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnCloseListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.SearchView+IOnCloseListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup_OnFitSystemWindowsListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu_OnDismissListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.PopupMenu+IOnDismissListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog+IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView_OnMenuItemClickListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_ItemAnimator_ItemAnimatorFinishedListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView+ItemAnimator+IItemAnimatorFinishedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.behavior.SwipeDismissBehavior_OnDismissListenerImplementor" generiert von: Google.Android.Material.Behavior.SwipeDismissBehavior+IOnDismissListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_ItemAnimator_ItemAnimatorFinishedListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView+IOnItemTouchListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider_OnShareTargetSelectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.ShareActionProvider+IOnShareTargetSelectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_OnMenuVisibilityListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar_OnMenuVisibilityListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar+IOnMenuVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider_OnShareTargetSelectedListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar+NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu_OnDismissListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird. Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnCloseListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView+IOnCloseListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_RecyclerListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView+IRecyclerListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView+IOnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_OnChildAttachStateChangeListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView+IOnChildAttachStateChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar_SnackbarActionClickImplementor" generiert von: Google.Android.Material.Snackbar.Snackbar+SnackbarActionClickImplementor, Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.Design.Widget.BottomNavigationView+IOnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout_OnOffsetChangedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.Design.Widget.AppBarLayout+IOnOffsetChangedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnQueryTextListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView+IOnQueryTextListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnSuggestionListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.SearchView+IOnSuggestionListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar_SnackbarActionClickImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.  Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher" generiert von: Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar+NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Application.Droid           
Fehler      Der Java-Typ "mono.androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView_OnChildAttachStateChangeListenerImplementor" wird von mehr als einem verwalteten Typ generiert. Ändern Sie das [Register]-Attribut, sodass nicht derselbe Java-Typ ausgegeben wird.    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.Design.Widget.NavigationView+IOnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView_OnQueryTextListenerImplementor" generiert von: AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.SearchView+IOnQueryTextListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   Application.Droid           
Fehler      "mono.com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor" generiert von: Android.Support.Design.Widget.BottomNavigationView+IOnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  Application.Droid
```

(rough) Translation:

```
Error    Java Type "typeXYZ" is generated by more than one managed Type. Change the [Register] attribute so that not the same Java type is emitted.`  
Error    "typeABC" generated by: Android.Support.XYZ, Xamarin.Android.Support.ABC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

I cannot get them away. I tried deleting the .vs, obj and bin folders, Rebuilds, restarted VS and my PC, even deleted and re-added the Xamarin.Forms NuGet Package from my project. I should mention, that this is a Xamarin.Forms solution, but the error is only in the Xamarin.Android Project.

The part that bugs me the most is, that I've clicked and "run" this before, one time on accident, one time on purpose, after which the project, looked completely unchanged. Same now, but I get error messages, and cannot create debug builds at all. Weirdly release builds still work fine.

---

### Update:

I've dug a bit deeper into this. At this point in time, I've updated VS from 16.7.3 to 16.7.5 (newest), run the Repair of Visual Studio, and went back on some earlier known working commit.
Two diffrences I noticed :

1. The "Migrate to AndroidX" Option is now missing,
2. The targeted Android Version is Android 9 (API Level 28)

This works as intended, building in debug finishes without errors

When I now up the targeted Android Version to Android 10 (API Level 29), I get the same errors as before. When I up tp to Android 11 (API level 30), I have to increase the LanguageVersion for the project to 8.0, because of some Interface Implementations, but I still get the same errors as before.

When I go back down to Android 9 everything is fine again.

Comment: The error from Xamarin.Android 10.1 is now an error because compatibility with the old GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies MSBuild task has been removed. You could firstly set the `TargetFrameworkVersion` as v10.0 .

Comment: I am currently using v11.

Comment: Try to set it as 10 and test again .

Comment: Same errors as before.

Comment: Where did you click the "migrate to AndroidX"? As I understand, migrate to AndroidX happens automatically when build projects targeting Android 29+ and XF 4.5+

Comment: Rightclicked on the Xamarin.Android Project, and there it is, directly under "Show Archives..."

Comment: Also I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.8

Comment: It appears that my VS don't have this option in the right click menu, may I ask which version of VS are you using? If it's not the latest, you can give the latest VS2019 16.7.5 a try.

Comment: updated from 16.7.3 to 16.7.5. Still the same errors, and also the option in the right click menu is still there.

Comment: Please see my update above.

Comment: Try set the dex compiler to d8 in the android options, if this doesn't work, then there's probably conflicts in dependencies after migrate to AndroidX, you'll need to consolidate your nuget package or any c# projects you're refering to to see if it's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Nicole Lu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12936075/nicole-lu-msft) I found the problem:

The Android Project referenced another project targeted at an older version of android (8.1) and also directly using older Android support libraries. After removing that project I can build in debug (and release) just fine.